# Can't install Ruby using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, debian

I'm running `Debian Wheezy` with kernel `2.6.32-028stab101.1`.

I just installed `Ruby` and `RVM`. The current installed version is

`ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]`,

however, I need version `1.8.7-p371` for my current code.

I tried running `rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p371`, but only get the following output:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: debian/7.0/x86_64/ruby-1.8.7-p371.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for debian, might require sudo password.
Hit http://plex.r.worldssl.net lucid Release.gpg
Hit http://plex.r.worldssl.net lucid Release
Hit http://www.plexapp.com lucid Release.gpg
Hit http://plex.r.worldssl.net lucid/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://www.plexapp.com lucid Release
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org sid Release.gpg
Hit http://www.plexapp.com lucid/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org sid Release
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org sid/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze Release.gpg
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://plex.originet.eu stable Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org sid/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze Release
Ign http://plex.originet.eu stable Release
Ign http://plex.originet.eu stable/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://www.plexapp.com lucid/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates Release
Ign http://www.plexapp.com lucid/main Translation-en
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/main Sources
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/contrib Sources
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/non-free Sources
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/main Sources
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/contrib Sources
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/non-free Sources
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://plex.r.worldssl.net lucid/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://plex.r.worldssl.net lucid/main Translation-en
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign http://plex.originet.eu stable/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign http://plex.originet.eu stable/main Translation-en
Err http://plex.originet.eu stable/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://debian.intergenia.de squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://plex.originet.eu/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried installing [readline](http://anlek.com/2011/01/rvm-install-1-8-7-p330-fails/), running `rvm mount`, inserted

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

in my `.zshrc`, but nothing worked.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with RVM. Rather, you have a broken source (seemingly `plex.originet.eu`) for `apt`. RVM rons `apt-get update` automatically, and this is `apt` complaining.

Comment: @Linuxios You're right. I noticed when running `apt-get update` that I get the same error. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Remove the broken host from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: @EinLama: Post as an answer.

Comment: I posted my above comment as answer as requested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within your apt hostlist, not within RVM.

Remove the broken host from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and you should be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

whats rvm -v say?

run `rvm get stable` to get the most current stable release

from there try just simply `rvm install 1.8.7`

after it installs you can run `rvm default 1.8.7` to set it as the default ruby

Comment: I already have the latest stable. Tried that. I have `rvm 1.19.1`